# Loop checkboxes and built JavaScript object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-literal

Hey all i am trying to figure out a way to add the data to a JS object when i loop to see which checkboxes on the page are checked:

```
jQuery('#doaction').click(function () {
    var bulkSelected = jQuery('#bulkAction').val();
    var checkCount = 1;

    if (bulkSelected == 0) {
        console.log('no bulk selected category');
        jQuery('#overlay-shade').fadeOut(300);
    } else {
        var doBulk = {
            called: '' + bulkSelected + '',
        };

        jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {                           
            if (jQuery(this).attr('id') != 'selectAll') {
                var isChecked = (this.checked ? true : false);

                if (isChecked == true) {
                    console.log(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
                    console.log(jQuery(this).attr('data-accnum'));
                }
                checkCount++;
            }
        });

    }
```

the **.attr('data-accnum')** has the number as you see below. I need it to be in this format:

*(checkbox name: accnum)*

```
var doBulk = {
    chk1: 52136523168,
    chk2: 54298851631
    ect..ect...
};
```

How can i do that?

Comment: I'm guessing the keys ("chk1", "chk2", etc.) are the `id` of the checkboxes?

Comment: @ian yes you would be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var doBulk = {};
jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {                           
    if (jQuery(this).attr('id') != 'selectAll') {
        var isChecked = (this.checked ? true : false);

        if (isChecked == true) {
            doBulk[jQuery(this).attr('id')] = +jQuery(this).attr("data-accnum");
        }
        checkCount++;
    }
});
console.log(doBulk);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector, as well as a [not](http://api.jquery.com/not) method which we use to only get all checked inputs that are not `#selectAll`.

Then you just add it to the `doBulk` object using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), accessing the `doBulk` object from within the `each` function is possible because javascript has [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

```
    var doBulk = {}
      , checked = jQuery('input[type=checkbox]:checked').not('#selectAll')
      , checkCount = checked.length;

    checked.each(function () {                           
      doBulk[this.id] = jQuery(this).attr('data-accnum');
    });
```